# For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, promise, jestjs

I have the following code which works.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

export const handle = someFunction(
  event =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        const sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: process.env.REGION });

        sns
           .publish()
           .promise()
           .then(data => {
              resolve({
                // some code
              });
           })
           .catch(er => {
              resolve({
               // some code
            });
           });
  })
);
```

But as soon as I move `sns.publish` into a separate function, I am getting the following error.

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
> "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

export const handle = someFunction(
  event =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        publishSNS();
  })
);

const publishSNS => {
   const sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: process.env.REGION });

   sns
   .publish()
   .promise()
   .then(data => {
      resolve({
        // some code
      });
   })
   .catch(er => {
      resolve({
       // some code
    });
   });
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're not calling `resolve` in `someFunction`'s promise

Comment: @Phix i have trimmed the function, it does have `resolve` in `someFunction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolve` is no longer in scope so it will throw out an error there. There's no reason to wrap the promise into another promise.

```
const publishSNS = () => {
   const sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: process.env.REGION });
   return sns.publish().promise();
};
```

Your other function can then handle it:

```
event => {
   return publishSNS()
          .then(data => /*handle success here */)
          .catch(err => /*handle error here */);
}
```